# Why this webapi2 attribute routing is not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have been struggling a WebApi2 setup based on Attribute Routing and I have run out of ideas what can be the problem. The following code is a newly created WebApi project by Visual Studio 2015. There are no changes in it. It simply does not work.

The response says the following:

```xml
<Error>
<Message>
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://.../services/webapi2/api/dummies/dummymethod'.
</Message>
<MessageDetail>
No type was found that matches the controller named 'dummies'.
</MessageDetail>
</Error>
```

What I did so far:

- I have checked the documentation whether I missed something - everything seems fine and fit for the documentation.
- I have checked the available answers here whether I find something useful - I have tried everything I found with no success

Thanks for any help in advance!

DummyController.cs

```cs
using System.Web.Http;

namespace WebApi2.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix( "Dummies" )]
    public class Dummy : ApiController
    {
        [Route("dummymethod")]
        public string Get()
        {
            return "asdasd";
        }
    }
}
```

WebApiConfig.cs

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace WebApi2
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Installed packages:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.4" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using attribute routing with a route prefix of only `dummies` so it would map to this URL

```
http://.../services/webapi2/dummies/dummymethod
```

So either use the above URL or update your route prefix to include `api` to match the URL used in your example

```
namespace WebApi2.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix( "api/Dummies" )]
    public class Dummy : ApiController
    {
        //GET api/dummies/dummymethod
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("dummymethod")]
        public string Get()
        {
            return "asdasd";
        }
    }
}
```

The above matches the request URI `http://.../services/webapi2/api/dummies/dummymethod`